# state variable value not changing

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-invocation, state-variable

I have very simple solidity code as below -

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

contract SaveData {
  uint public salary;

  function setSalary(uint input) public {
        salary=input;
  }

  function getSalary() public view returns(uint) {
        return salary;
  }

}
```

I am calling `savedata.setSalary(5000)` from eth console. It generates a transaction. However after mining the transaction when I ran `savedata.getSalary()` it always return me 0. I tried allocating a lot of GAS as well.

Comment: Sounds like your node is not synced. Also, make sure to `await` for the function to complete, or resolve the promise it returns before you read the state variable.

Comment: Is it on public blockchain?  Could you show transaction receipt for the transaction that supposed to change state variable?

Comment: I suppose you mean SaveData.setSalary(5000), not lowercased savedata as you wrote...

Answer (score 3):

Try following commands after migration. I am using truffle console.

- SaveData.deployed().then((instance) => instance.setSalary(1000))
- SaveData.deployed().then((instance) => instance.getSalary())

and its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty late to reply. I think remove the `view` and your problem will be solved. You are obviously making some changes here. View is for read operations only.